# How to get node's line numbers with XML::LibXML

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2

I am trying to process a XML with [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aLibXML) and report lines where certain elements are. According to docs linked above, `line_numbers` option should do the trick, but I keep getting 0. The code:

```
use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new({ line_numbers => 1 });
my $xml = $parser->load_xml(location => 'some.xml');

for my $node ($xml->findnodes('//function')) {
    warn $node->nodePath,"\n";
    warn $node->line_number,"\n";
}
```

The node is found, my output is

```
/database/functions/function
0
```

Any idea how to get it working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation:

---

> ```
> $lineno = $node->line_number();
> ```
>
> This function returns the line number where the tag was found during
>   parsing. If a node is added to the document the line number is 0.
>   Problems may occur, if a node from one document is passed to another
>   one.
>
> If the line_numbers flag of the parser was not activated before
>   parsing, line_number() will always return 0.

---

Was the node added during the course of the XML manipulation?

---

*It wasn't*. A closer investigation showed that the offending function was the `load_xml`. Replace it with the following and it works fine:

```
my $xml = $parser->parse_file('some.xml');
```

Comment: It was not manipulated, you can see full snippet above. Just load -> findnodes -> line_number.

Comment: It looks like only `$parser->load_xml` is problematic, while `XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $file, line_numbers => 1)` works also fine. Looks like the cloning in `load_xml` is culprit.

Comment: for everyone else. This is how it worked for me - my $dom = XML::LibXML->new({ line_numbers => 1 })->parse_file($xmlfilename);